# Extracting the last numerical and its trailing text in R

Tags: r, regex

From a string such as

```
s <- c("123 John 80 kg", "456 Paul 23 shifts  9 l", "Diane 155 cm")
```

I wish to extract only the last numerical and the trailing text. My desired result looks like this:

```
"80 kg" "9 l" "155 cm"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a regular expression:

```
sub(".*\\b(\\d+\\s+\\w+)", "\\1", s)
1] "80 kg"  "9 l"    "155 cm"
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer works the examples that I gave. For anyone who might have a similar case - this solution does not generalise to cases such as "678 Oscar 60kg". Ronak' solution with stringi does.

Comment: If you want to allow no space between the number and the letters use `".*\\b(\\d+\\s*\\w+)"`

Comment: @NikolayNenov that's why it's helpful for your question to include the cases that you need to be able to adjust to, so folks can address those stipulations without having to go back and revise. If your examples don't contain a `60kg` example, we can't know that you need one.

Comment: Thanks @camille - it's useful to remind the need to give relevant examples to anyone who does not find it blatantly obvious. Please note, my initial comment is meant to inform anyone who might stumble on a similar problem that the solution might not work for their case. Apologies if it came out as a criticism ;)

Answer (score 5):

Try the following regex which reads like the requirements:

```
stringr::str_extract(s, "\\d+\\D*$")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `stri_extract_last_regex`

```
stringi::stri_extract_last_regex(s, "\\d+\\s+\\w+")
#[1] "80 kg"  "9 l"    "155 cm"
```

Answer (score 1):

Or using `regmatches/regexpr` from `base R`

```
regmatches(s, regexpr("\\d+[^0-9]*$", s))
#[1] "80 kg"  "9 l"    "155 cm"
```